# How to make multiple right bar button items stack vertically in navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How can I add a UIlabel to the area in green? (it will be within the navigation bar)

[image]

I was able to add the logo as a button image in rightBarButtonItem, but I can't google a way to add a label to the nav bar in this specific position.

After reading around I'm thinking maybe I have to create a custom view that would contain the logo and a UILabel, arrange them vertically within that view, and then place that view in rightBarButtonItem?

edit: This is a unique problem from other answers here in that I am looking for how to add a UILabel to an area of the NavigationBar that is outside of the "rightBarButtonItem" area. Using rightBarButtonItem or setting a custom view to appear within rightBarButtonItem does not achieve what I am looking for. I want a UILabel to appear in the NavBar on the right side aligned vertically with the "Today" title.

Comment: Yes, You need to create a custom view for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom view on right of navigation bar Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876060/how-to-add-custom-view-on-right-of-navigation-bar-swift)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: This is the right direction but how can I extend the view further down vertically? Right now, it gets cut off by something no matter how large I make the view's Y value. See here: https://imgur.com/a/7BPR1R2 (the custom view background is set to red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that using a custom header within the collectionView is the way to go (rather than trying to place a UILabel into the navigationBar via a custom UIView into the rightBarButtonItem space). This worked for me because I wanted the title and date to disappear upon scrolling anyway. Basically this mimics the "Today" tab in the iOS App Store, and my solution finally achieved what I was looking for.

Finished result:
[image]

The 2 posts that helped me set up the collectionView header and attach the labels are here:

1. [How to add UICollectionView Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193641/how-to-add-uicollectionview-header)
2. [Display Section Header UICollectionReusableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694923/display-section-header-uicollectionreusableview)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code snippet:

```
let containerView = UIView()
...

let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containerView)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but How can I get the containerView to extend further down? Right now, no matter how large I set the Y value, it gets cut off by something. See here (I set the view background to red): https://imgur.com/a/7BPR1R2

Comment: Oh, I'm not exactly sure, but you can try autoresizingMask with flexible height or flexible bottom margin, or you can try to override intrinsic content size or sizeThatFits method